# How to open a file without any extension in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, download, file-extension

I recently downloaded a file but it just looks plain, i mean no icon like winzip or anything and in the 'Type' column it just shows 'file'. i have no clue how to open such kind of file.

Comment: Does it have a name at least?  And where did you get it?

Comment: What did you think you were downloading?

Comment: @DarthAndroid a winzip file

Comment: add a .zip file extension to the file and then try extracting.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon Problem solved, .zip didn't work. I downloaded 7-zip and was able to open the file.

Comment: What are you so furious about? Why so many Negative votes, i just asked something related to my problem. is it wrong to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to open the file with 7-zip, winzip didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the file in WordPad. Usually these extension-less files are text files from OS X or Linux; If it's just gibberish, then it's probably an executable program for one of these operating systems (more likely linux, in that case).

Answer (score 1):

You might well have downloaded a Linux executable. 
You cannot run these files on Microsoft Windows.